# Entity Framework fears for an enterprise solution

Tags: entity-framework

We are considering MVC 4 for a significantly sized application.

Our DBA is nervous about "losing control" over the database, and doesn't like the idea of application code defining/changing the database structure.  Which I can understand.  He thinks it's great for a one man team or small shop, but doesn't see how it fits into an enterprise solution with a DBA on staff.  Where would he fit in on the process?

I imagine EF is widely used in enterprise environments, are there any good articles to better inform us on how EF is utilized in contrast to a traditional environment where coders code and DB guys manage the tables?

Comment: Use DB first, then he will be happy.

Comment: DBA? EF? What do they mean? Also your question is very opinionated, which makes it ill-suited for a programming Q&A site. Consider revising your question in a fashion that allows us to answer specific, more objective aspects of the problem.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be a candidate for stackexchange.com/programmers.

Comment: Oops, I meant programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Even with Entity Framework 6, you can still easily do **database-first** development (which let's the DBA control the DB structure fully, as today) ....

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have a misunderstanding of what Entity Framework is, and how it is and can be used.

Entity Framework is known as an ORM or Object Relational Mapper.  There is nothing inherent to ORM's that takes any control away from a DBA.

It's true that EF can generate tables, data models, sql, etc.. but it doesn't *HAVE* to.  Nor do other ORM's.  At it's heart, an ORM simply takes a result set, and maps it to a collection of objects.  This can be accomplished with Stored Procedures just as well.

Most people like to do ad-hoc queries, and EF is great for that, but if your DBA requires that all queries be written by him (or approved by him, and used a sprocs) then it can certainly be used that way.

The current version of Entity Framework really only supports queries mapping, but EF 6, due to be released by the end of the year will add support for Insets, Update and Deletes as well.  You can do those today as queries, but they don't map to objects.

But in all honesty, your DBA should really face facts that DBA's are becoming increasingly less necessary.  They will always have a place, but they really need to accept that they can't have the iron fist control over query execution that they once had.  Users (and thus developers) are demanding more dynamic queries, and that means executing generated sql.

Comment: I really would have to disagree, as a DBA working on an enterprise scale project with EF5 I think the role of the DBA is more important than ever. I also feel that with the EF model available for developers to access however they want, the DBA does indeed lose a lot of control over the performance of the database, and as such isn't always in a position where they can improve data access code. And there will most definitely be performance issues to be overcome on any large scale database application, my experience has been that .NET developers are just not well suited to that task. YMMV

Comment: @KevinDahl - Obviously, when developers take over ad-hoc query generation, they need to be responsible for the performance of the query.  If they're not "up to the task" then they should be replaced by someone that is, or they shouldn't be using the tool in that way.  Alternatively, YOU can step up and learn Entity Framework, since it's just another query language.  My point is, bolting everything down tight is not a solution, because it prohibits the business from being as flexible as it needs to be.  By trying to be part of the solution, you're becoming a bigger problem.

Comment: Obvious or not, I haven't found that it generally works that way. I'm also fairly well versed in EF/LINQ, and do what I can to point out bad patterns like excessive Includes, or LINQ queries within foreach loops, etc. When you're a team of one or two DBAs with 10-15 developers though, it's an uphill battle. I think the DBA in the original question is right to be wary, because I have a hard time believing that my experience is unique.

Comment: @KevinDahl - Yet you somehow believe 1 or 2 DBA's with 15 developers will be just fine writing all their SQL queries?  Obviously you can't control the situation like you want, or you would be doing so..

Comment: No, I don't - and that's kind of my point. Using EF in no way removes the requirement for a strong team of development DBAs. If anything, it makes them that much more necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is a bit general, but if I remember correctly [Microsoft® .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X) book has a very detailed chapter/setion on Data Access Layer and ORMs in general.